# How to render Hebrew characters correctly (in reverse)

Tags: fonts, hebrew

Pasting a line in my Text Editor (Sublime) reverses the order of the letters like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6hpj.jpg). How do I orient the letters in reverse so I don't have to retype them or programmatically reverse them and hardcode the reversed text. That is, I can put them in left-to-right order, yet render them right-to-left.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{he.ttf}
\begin{document}
א  בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you click on the tag [hebrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew) you will find many examples demonstrating how to set text right-to-left using [bidi](https://ctan.org/pkg/bidi) and friends

Comment: @DG' that is not true, I looked through the first 5 pages of [hebrew] tag and found nothing related to Noto font and/or rtl rendering worthwhile.

Comment: Take a look at the `babel` manual for examples. And also the samples here: https://github.com/latex3/babel/tree/master/samples .

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell LaTeX that your text is in Hebrew. One package to do so is `polyglossia`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\begin{document}
א  בְּרֵאשִׁית, בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם, וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You also know the Hebrew language perfectly :-)